# Button Design Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, button, wpf-animation

On my application I have a side bar which looks like this:

[image]

*The Admin bit is just a header*

Now at the moment I have coded these to be `Buttons`. They don't really have any effect on the click or anything. I want to change these to `TabItems` so it has the effect of coming out to the side.

I have tried doing this but when I add a `width` to a `TabItem` the effect goes and it just looks like a `Button`.

[image]

As you can see that the `TabItem` just looks like a `Button`, the effect has gone.

Do you guys have any suggestions on what I could do to make mine look better with an `Animation` or how I can fix the `TabItem` issue?

**EDIT:**

I have changed my TabItems to Buttons, but I am having a massive problem. I have 10 different buttons on the left hand side and when I click one, the animation appears and it ends up like this:

[image]

But as you can see from the picture, when I click another button below the same animation happens but the previous button clicked doesn't go back to the normal state.

**How can reset the storyboard animation on the previous clicked button, when I click another button.**

Comment: Why not use the buttons but add your animations to those?

Comment: @Killercam Never had any experience with 'Wpf Animation' that's why I tried to use the TabItem. Is it easy to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, using a stack of buttons in this case is preferable. Using a `TabControl` here does not seem necessary and will complicate things for you. Check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613593%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a great tutorial on doing what you want.

I hope this helps.

---

*Edit. to address question about shape...*

If you want to inherit the default system colours/styles for a Button you can use TemplateBindings within the button Template. For example, if you wanted to create a custom-shaped button that had the same background colour as the system one

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <!-- circle to have inherited colour -->
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="50" Width="50" />
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The `Ellipse` will then inherit the background colour from the `Button`, however it is set. To do this in an animation will be more involved, but not at all impossible...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am going to read through this article now. With WPF animation it is possible for the shape of the button to change on hover over?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible. Almost anything is possible with WPF. I have edited the question to show you how you can change the shape statically. To do this in an animation will require you to read into the details...